# Recyclerview update,delete

Tags: java, android, json, sdk, android-recyclerview

I have made a discussion forum where the person who is logged in can ask a question and the main forum shows all the question put up by a different user. everyone can answer the question also and rate.

The problem is when is add the question from adding question activity it is going back to discussion forum but not refreshing. What I want is as soon as the question is asked, it should show in the discussion forum and the user should have the ability to modify and delete that question. everything is dynamic how to delete the dynamic data as well.

this is my discussion forum code

```
package com.example.pitechnologies.pkguru.fragment;


public class DiscussionForumFragment extends Fragment {
TextView title;
RelativeLayout askquestion;
public View view;
UserProfileData userProfileData;
String U_id;
EditText que, desc;
TextView btnask;
String uname;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
ImageView imgSpoon;
final List<Model_Forum> unilist = new ArrayList<>();

private static String TAG = DiscussionForumFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private RecyclerView forumrecyclerView;
private ForumList_Adapter forumAdapter;
public DiscussionForumFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    super.onStart();
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
  //   forumdata();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_discussion_forum, container, false);
    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.forumtitle);
    title.setText("DISCUSSION FORUM");
    askquestion = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.askquestion);

    askquestion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(PreferenceHelper.getInstance(getActivity()).getSemid() == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityLoginSignUp.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityQuestionaire.class);
                intent.putExtra("uu_id", U_id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    forumrecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_forum);
    forumrecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    forumrecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(DiscussionForumFragment.this.getActivity()));
    forumAdapter = new ForumList_Adapter(DiscussionForumFragment.this.getContext(), unilist);
    forumrecyclerView.setAdapter(forumAdapter);
    forumrecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    imgSpoon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_spoon);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pg_loader);
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    forumdata();
    return view;

}
public void forumdata() {
    unilist.clear();
   /* final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();*/
    linearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ObjectAnimator flip = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imgSpoon, "rotationY", 0f, 180f);
    flip.setDuration(800);
    flip.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    flip.start();
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URLconstant.FORUM, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.d("data", data.toString());
                JSONArray datarray = data.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < datarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject secondobj = datarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("secondobj", secondobj.toString());
                    Model_Forum model_forum = new Model_Forum();
                    model_forum.mforum_id = secondobj.getString("forum_id");
                    model_forum.mqst = secondobj.getString("qst");
                    model_forum.mqst_description = secondobj.getString("qst_description");
                    model_forum.mqst_uid = secondobj.getString("qst_uid");
                    model_forum.muser_id = secondobj.getString("user_id");
                    model_forum.mfullname = secondobj.getString("fullname");
                    model_forum.muniver_id = secondobj.getString("univer_id");
                    model_forum.mbranchid = secondobj.getString("branchid");
                    model_forum.msemid = secondobj.getString("semid");
                    model_forum.mcollegeid = secondobj.getString("collegeid");
                    model_forum.muser_image = secondobj.getString("user_image");
                    model_forum.mq_date = secondobj.getString("q_date");
                    model_forum.mq_time = secondobj.getString("q_time");
                    unilist.add(model_forum);
                }
                if (getContext() != null) {
                   /* forumAdapter = new ForumList_Adapter(DiscussionForumFragment.this.getContext(), unilist);
                    forumrecyclerView.setAdapter(forumAdapter);*/
                    forumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //  pDialog.dismiss();
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            //  pDialog.dismiss();
            linearLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    MySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}
```